# Return dataframe rows

Tags: python

[image]

I am quite new to Python and I have a small problem that I am struggling to solve. I have a dataframe from a csv file (image attached) and I need to return rows from the data frame that match conditions applied to specific columns. However, the trick here is to also return the two previous rows from the filtered dataframe (once the condition is satisfied). More specifically, I need to return rows where the 'Sanctions' column has the value 'Sanction' and the two rows previous to this row. Any 'Pythonic' way to solve this? Currently, I am using a list comprehension technique which is very slow. A little help will be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I have attached a glimpse of my data as an image.

Comment: showing an example of your current code will make it a lot easier to give an answer

Comment: Trying to use something like this, but it is not working: df.ix[i:i+2] for i in range(df.shape[0]-3) if df.ix[i+2]['Sanctions']== ’Sanction’ ] . 

I have defined this as a function: 
def seq(df):
    for i in range(df.shape[0]-3):
        while df.ix[i+2]['Sanctions']=='Sanction':
            df=df.ix[i:i+2]
        return df
But cannot seem to apply it to my dataframe!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is `shift`:

```
test = df['Sanctions']== 'Sanction' #create a true/false list of rows that = 'Sanction
test1 = test.shift(-1) #shift list by 1 to get previous row
test2 = test.shift(-2) #shift list by 2 to get 2nd previosu row

df[(test == True) |(test1==True) | (test2==True)] #select rows from df where any of test or test1 or test2 are true
```

I think this will give you what you are after. (Although personally I think a method that doesn't rely on the results being sorted would be better.)

Comment: Worked wonders! Can you explain what the last line is exactly doing? I know they are 'OR' operators but how does it retain the values in the dataframe? Please also elaborate on your comment: 'method that doesn't reply on the results being sorted would be better'? I am after extracting sequences of the event codes which resulted in a sanction.

Comment: I've added some comments to help explain. Regarding my comment about method: currently you are assuming that the data is sorted by date. If, for some reason, your data becomes unsorted the current code will still work but you will get the wrong results.